# Programa en vb6 funciona el el ide pero crashea el ejecutable

Tags: vb6, windows-server, compilacion

En primer lugar un saludo a la comunidad.

El motivo de este post es que estoy haciendo modificaciones en un programa de chat en *VB6* el cual funciona en el IDE sin problemas y se queda en la barra de tareas, como debe ser. El problema es que, al compilarlo y ejecutarlo, en el registro de eventos sale el siguiente error.

```
Nombre de la aplicación con errores: CHAT.exe, versión: 1.0.0.69, marca de tiempo: 0x5f325d6a
Nombre del módulo con errores: unknown, versión: 0.0.0.0, marca de tiempo: 0x00000000
Código de excepción: 0xc000041d
Desplazamiento de errores: 0x747d4d0e
Identificador del proceso con errores: 0xf08
Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01d66fbe08be0a9f
Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores: 
Ruta de acceso del módulo con errores: unknown
Identificador del informe: 4708b1fd-dbb1-11ea-8f9e-00155d44f01b
Nombre completo del paquete con errores: %14
Identificador de aplicación relativa del paquete con errores: %15
```

El sistema donde lo compilo y ejecuto es un Windows 2008 de 64 bits. He mirado el tema de permisos y compatibilidades, pero no tira.

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Lo estás compilando en un Windows 2008 server?

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser un problema del sistema operativo mas que en la programacion. Si no se puede ejecutar como aplicacion stand-alone, puede que la aplicacion se este bloqueando por DEP ([Prevencion de ejecucion de datos][1]).

Si la aplicacion es confiable, puedes intentar *desactivar DEP* **solo** para esta aplicacion (Asumo que es una aplicacion de 32 bits compilada en VB6).

- Ir a Propiedades del sistema-> Opciones de rendimiento-> Prevención de ejecución de datos
- Active DEP para todos los programas y servicios, excepto los que seleccione

  - Seleccionar la aplicacion (.exe) que se desea desactivar
  - (No se puede desactivar para aplicaciones de 64 bit)